# How to fix footer height on my website https://ekasya.com?

Tags: wordpress

How to fix footer height on my website https://ekasya.com?

I tried this code

```
.footer-widgets {     
  padding: 10px 0 0 0 !important;
}  

#sidebar-footer.widget-area .col-md-12 .widget {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

But nothing happend using shopekeeper theme please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change site footer padding:

```
#site-footer {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, brother love you really :) it works and what if I need to shrink little more and how about spacing between social media icons and menus?